# Running widgets in hosted mode in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, widget

I am building complicated widgets for Google Web Toolkit. These widgets are compiled to a jarfile, which I include in other projects. At the moment I have to compile the jar and startup the other project in hosted mode to test my widget. This is rather slow. Does somebody if it's possible to test widgets in hosted mode directly?

My structure is as follows:

- com.example.gwt with a xxx.gwt.xml file
- com.example.components.emailform with the composite and a uibinder xml file

What else do I need to run the hosted mode? I do not need any client/server interaction, and I would like to keep any additional files to a minimum, in order to not mess up my jar.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is to add an entrypoint definition to your module xxx.gwt.xml file.
In the entrypoint class you can instantiate your widget and add it to a `RootLayoutpanel` or `RootPanel`.

Module xml file:
`<entry-point class="com.xxx.xxx.MyWidgetTest" />`

MyWidgetTest.class:

```
public class MyWidgetTest implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
         MyWidget myWidget = new MyWidget();
         RootLayoutPanel.add(myWidget);
    }
}
```

Even if you don't use a web-server you probably have to add a host page (html page) where you load your nocache.js bootstrap file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="xxx.nocache.js" />
```

You can create a second xxx.gwt.xml file that doesn't contain the entrypoint definition. This second xxx.gwt.xml module file can be packaged with your jar file (using Ant or maven) and you can exclude the MyWidgetTest class file from your jar package.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at GWT documentation regarding [modules](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/wizards/gwt/module.html) and [libraries](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/wizards/gwt/library.html). I guess that is what you are looking for.